# Read file from GH repository (Probot)

Tags: github, probot

I'm using Probot/Octocat to run some code checks, one of the things I'm doing is checking against a list of breaking changes in a separate repository on an internal package update. Is there any easy way to read a file (.md) from a separate private repository easily within Probot on a pull request action, or do I need a manual request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Probot's Octokit instance](https://probot.github.io/docs/github-api/) to interact with GitHub API in an easy way.

Checking Octokit's API Docs, you can find [here](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#repos-get-content) a way to get the content of a file:

```js
context.octokit.rest.repos.getContent({
  owner,
  repo,
  path
});
```

I used Octokit's API for reading a file [in this script](https://github.com/oscard0m/octoherd-script-add-cache-to-node-github-action/blob/b37858b0dd1359b4745f2201335b1f129235a029/script.js#L40-L46) if you want to check an example

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get content from a specific branch? (Other than main/master)

Comment: Yes, there is an optional parameter: `ref` where you can specify that. You can find the reference [here](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#repos-get-content)